# Maximize MATLAB figure's WINDOW - not the figure

Tags: matlab, window, figure, maximize

What I want is to maximize the window of the figure as if I clicked it with mouse, but not the figure itself. Because all the techniques of enlarging figure do really make it bigger, but the window remains restored though fits to the figure.

Here is the command I use to enlarge a figure:

```
figure ('units',' normalized', 'position', [0 0 1 1]);
```

The difference between enlarged window and maximized is as follows:

enlarged:
[image]

maximized: 
[image]

Look at the top right corner of the window, which is where one clicks with a mouse to maximize/restore, see the change. See also how the maximized window fills tight the whole screen and doesn't go under the taskbar either by its color.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code, that you wrote so far?

Comment: `figure ('units',' normalized', 'position', [0 0 1 1])` This is one option. There are others, but all of them address figure size to which window accordingly fits. My point is to maximize window so the figure stretches.

Comment: Edit the question please, as opposed to adding code in comments. Also: please add pictures with the current and desired behaviour so we can see what you want.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between figure and figure window.

Comment: @Adriaan, I've added more detailed explanation to the question.

Comment: @excaza, you can see the distinction in the edition I've made to the question.

Comment: The wording of your question is still incredibly unclear but I think what you're looking for is talked about in [this Undocumented MATLAB article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/minimize-maximize-figure-window). `Normalized` units for a top level figure are based on the screen size and do not account for whether or not the Windows taskbar is minimized.

Comment: @excaza,
The article you've provided answered my question exactly, thank you. The command I needed is this:
`figureHandle.JavaFrame.setMaximized(true);`
Where `figureHandle` is variable storing the figure's handle.
Though there is still some problem, potentially critical. The property `JavaFrame` will be obsoleted in future Matlab release as informed by the command's warning.
`Warning: figure JavaFrame property will be obsoleted in a future release. For more information see the JavaFrame resource on the MathWorks web site.`
https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/dev/javaframe.html

Comment: You'll have to cross that bridge when it comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the following article, kindly provided by the user `excaza`:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/minimize-maximize-figure-window

Essentially, it breaks down to operating the `JavaFrame` figure's property. It is absent in the handle, hidden from user, so just operate as if it's there.

Pay attention to the pause factor described in the article's comments. Without it nothing works, because of some Java issues related to time shortage between figure call and Java readiness.
It is suggested in the comments to add before the maximizing/minimizing `drawnow; pause(0.1);`. For me it works without `drawnow;`. Also, any infinitesimal argument will work for pause, if you should, like `pause(1e-1000000);` for example.

Comment: Note that this is not officially supported by matlab, which means that things may change suddenly and unexpected. Still I can understand your problem. I have been there as well (in the waste sea of unsupported features of Matlab) in some way or another. Still, no software can support everything and I appreciate that Matlab allows the user to use unsupported features.

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB R2018a, there is the property "WindowState" to maximize a figure like you want:

```
figure("WindowState", "maximized");
```

See the details at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html.